# C++ 11 Move Semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, variable-assignment, move-semantics

I'm trying to understand how C++ 11 move semantics works.  I have implemented a class which wraps a pointer to a String object but neither the move constructor nor the move assignment operator are being called as expected.

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 through Eclipse CDT:

Could you help me understand the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class StringPointerWrapper {
public:

    // Default constructor with default value
    StringPointerWrapper(const std::string& s = "Empty"): ps(new std::string(s)) {
        std::cout << "Default constructor: " << *ps << std::endl;
    }

    //Copy constructor
    StringPointerWrapper(const StringPointerWrapper& other): ps(new std::string(*other.ps)) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor: " << *other.ps << std::endl;
    }

    //Copy assignment operator
    StringPointerWrapper& operator=(StringPointerWrapper other) {
        std::cout << "Assignment operator (ref): " << *other.ps << std::endl;
        swap(ps, other.ps);
        return *this;
    }


    //Alternate copy assignment operator
    /*StringPointerWrapper& operator=(StringPointerWrapper& other) {
        std::cout << "Assignment operator (val)" << std::endl;
        //We need to do the copy by ourself
        StringPointerWrapper temp(other);
        swap(ps, temp.ps);
        return *this;
    }*/

    //Move constructor
    StringPointerWrapper(StringPointerWrapper&& other) noexcept : ps(nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Move constructor: " << *other.ps << std::endl;
        ps = other.ps;
        other.ps = nullptr;
    }

    //Move assignment operator
    StringPointerWrapper& operator= (StringPointerWrapper&& other) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Move assignment operator: " << *other.ps << std::endl;
        if(this != &other) {
            delete ps;
            ps = other.ps;
            other.ps = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }


    //Destructor
    ~StringPointerWrapper() {
        std::cout << "Destroying: " << *this << std::endl;
        delete ps;
    }
private:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, StringPointerWrapper& spw) {
            os << *spw.ps;
            return os;
        }
        std::string *ps;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    StringPointerWrapper spw1("This is a string");
    StringPointerWrapper spw2;
    StringPointerWrapper spw3("This is another string");
    StringPointerWrapper spw4 = {"This is a const string"};
    StringPointerWrapper spw5(StringPointerWrapper("String for move constructor"));
    std::cout << "spw2 before: " << spw2 << std::endl;
    spw2 = spw3;
    std::cout << "spw2 after: " << spw2 << std::endl;
    StringPointerWrapper spw6 = StringPointerWrapper("String for move assignment");
    std::cout << spw1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << spw2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << spw3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << spw4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << spw5 << std::endl;
    std::cout << spw6 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Before anything, this might not be the best example to understand move semantics. `std::string` is basically a wrapper around a `char *` so you are building a wrapper around a pointer to a wrapper around a pointer to a char array.

Comment: Can you give the output ?

Comment: The output is:

Default constructor: This is a string
Default constructor: Empty
Default constructor: This is another string
Default constructor: This is a const string
Default constructor: String for move constructor
spw2 before: Empty
Copy constructor: This is another string
Assignment operator (ref): This is another string
Destroying: Empty
spw2 after: This is another string
Default constructor: String for move assignment
This is a string
This is another string
This is another string
This is a const string
String for move constructor
String for move assignment
All destructors called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move constructors are not being called because the compiler is eliding the constructor as an optimization. If you pass `-fno-elide-constructors` in your compiler invocation, you can disable this.

However, you have issues because your move constructor is just using the pointer from `other`, which is deleted soon after. It doesn't really make sense to hold the `std::string` as a pointer, you should just hold it directly and call `std::move` in your move assignment operator and move constructor.

Comment: Now the move constructor is called but not the move assignment operator.

Comment: That's because you aren't doing any assignment in your example apart from `spw2 = spw3`. `T t = T{}` is copy-initialization, not copy-assignment.

Comment: Besides, your assignment operators are ambiguous when called with an r-value.

Comment: What about this: StringPointerWrapper spw6 = StringPointerWrapper("String for move assignment");

Comment: That's copy-initialization. `StringPointerWrapper spw6; spw6 = StringPointerWrapper("String for move assignment");` would call the move-assignment operator if it weren't ambiguous.

Comment: You are right. Now the compiler gives: ..\ConstructorTest.cpp:92:85: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' in 'spw6 = StringPointerWrapper((* & std::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"String for move assignment"), (*(const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))'

Comment: Indeed if I uncomment the other copy assignment operator, StringPointerWrapper& operator=(StringPointerWrapper& other), the ambiguity goes away and the move assignment operator is used.

Comment: Your best option is to just remove the move-assignment operator. Because you have a copy-and-swap-based assignment operator already and a move-constructor, you're making use of move semantics anyway because the compiler will call the move-constructor when creating the copy.

Comment: Usually constness of the parameter in the copy assignment "is used" by the overloading logic to decide if calling the move assignment or the copy assignment.

Answer (score 2):

> StringPointerWrapper spw5(StringPointerWrapper("String for move constructor"));

This invokes the default constructor because the compiler has decided to optimize this by not creating a temporary (i.e., it has decided to do `StringPointerWrapper spw5("String for move constructor")`). Instead force a move by performing `StringPointerWrapper spw5(std::move(StringPointerWrapper("String for move constructor")));`.

> StringPointerWrapper spw6 = StringPointerWrapper("String for move assignment");

Again, the compiler invokes the default constructor by optimizing away the creation of the temporary.

**Note:** your `operator<<` needs to guard against *null* pointers. For example,

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, StringPointerWrapper& spw) {
    if (spw.ps)
         os << (spw.ps);
        else
            os << "null";
    return os;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the compiler yourself to move things with std::move

try:

```
 StringPointerWrapper spw5(std::move(StringPointerWrapper("String for move constructor")));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Applying the suggested change the program crashes. :(

Comment: The compiler does decide on what to move. it moves r-values. `std::move` basically turns an l-value into an r-value so the move semantics can kick in. `std::move` doesn't do the moving (quite a terrible name..)

Comment: Anyway my expectation is that the return value of StringPointerWrapper("String for move constructor")) is a nonconst rvalue reference. As a result it should bind to both the copy constructor and the move constructor. Anyway the copy constructor has a const lvalue reference (const StringPointerWrapper& other) and as a result overloading resolution should chose the move constructor that has a non const rvalue reference (StringPointerWrapper&& other). Am I wrong?

Comment: @salvo what does the console print before the crash?

Comment: The output before crash is:
Default constructor: This is a string
Default constructor: Empty
Default constructor: This is another string
Default constructor: This is a const string
Default constructor: String for move constructor
Move constructor: String for move constructor